# Can the "Full Page" button for code snippets be made to rerun the code?

Tags: feature-request

Many code snippets related to canvas/webgl and maybe other HTML fatures look up the size of things at initialization time. This means clicking "Full Page" often fails.

Sure you could ask every developer to be a perfect coder but it seems more friendly to just reload the code. Example: Click "Show Code Snippet" then "Run Code Snippet" then "Full Page"

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// make canvas full size of page
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0";
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("The X should fill the page", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

In order to fix this sample so that "Full Page" works I need to totally refactor the code. I need to put all the drawing code into a function, call it once at init time and then setup an event handler to call it on resize. Or I need to render continuously with requestAnimationFrame and check for the size of the something changing (the window, the canvas). None of those are often relevant to the question or answer whereas conversely, quite often, a sample will draw something that is larger than the default display area for stackoverflow and so the user needs to press "Full Page" to see it all except it doesn't work for the reasons mentioned.

Worse, the default preview area when actually editing the snippet is a different size, usually larger, than the result area when viewing the snippet inline. That means the person making the snippet is unlikely to notice that although they might be able to see the relevant output in the snippet editor, a person looking at the snippet inline will not see the relevant output.

Example: Check out the message on the bottom right.  Click "Show Code Snippet" then "Run Code Snippet".  Oops, it only shows up when editing the snippet.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;


ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Put Msg in bottom right", canvas.width - 10, canvas.height - 20);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And, to make it even worse, there's no "Full Page" button when editing the snippet.

The solution seems simple, reload the code when "Full Page" is clicked. Can this be made to happen?

Comment: This should receive more attention. As someone who hangs around HTML/CSS tag, this one bugs me many times.

Comment: What is worse is that this is a regression. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794754/205696 used to work perfect in "Full page" mode but now it hardly illustrate the point of the answer.