# Add a "Run code snippet" button to a Full Page snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

The feature request is ultimately very similar to [Can the "Full Page" button for code snippets be made to rerun the code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305807/215552). However, that question has not seen much activity for a year, so I'm bringing it up again, with a twist.

Instead of simply rerunning the code snippet when the Full Page button is clicked, I'd rather see a "Run code snippet" button on the Full Page screen such that I can rerun the code as often as I'd like (for instance, after resizing my browser).

This feature would allow people to write snippets without adding extra code just to handle the Stack Snippet's Full Page feature. Such code can distract from the code under consideration, especially when written with less care, which can cause additional, irrelevant bugs to the code.

This would require some design considerations and of course developer time to implement, but I believe it would be worth that effort.

Please consider adding this functionality to Stack Snippets.

Comment: I've just come across a question where it would have been very useful to be able to re-run the snippet in fullscreen mode (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479388/how-to-hide-the-overflow-image-on-the-bottom-right-with-animation). In fact _any_ question based around an auto-run CSS animation requires this feature. Could this please be implemented?

Comment: This would still be really useful in certain situations; maybe a userscript could fill this gap?